# ReSharper wrapping test result stacktraces?

Tags: c#, testing, resharper, mstest, word-wrap

ReSharper 4.5's test runner will run MSTest tests out of the box, and that's what I'm doing.  When a test fails, I click on the test to see the stacktrace and the failure reason.  The pane I'm clicking in to do this is the "Unit Test Sessions" pane.

The lower half of this pane (or the right half, if you have it configured that way) shows the reason and stacktrace for the failure.  This section/pane does not word wrap, so I have to use the mouse to scroll left and right all the time.

How can I make this reason/stacktrace pane word wrap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For such issues, you'd better fire a bug report to JetBrains guys via ReSharper menu | Send Feedback. That can help you better discuss with the team instead of us normal users.

Answer (score 0):

There is an open issue here [http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RSRP-192009#content-tab=1) which you can vote for.

At present in the History Tab it says they plan to fix it in 6.0 Beta.